# How can I increase my chances of finding Awestones?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls 2, there is the Covenant of Champions, which requires you to find Awestones that drop from certain enemies, at certain rates. For example, any invader has a 100% chance to drop an Awestone. Some NPC's also have 100% chance of dropping one.

However, other enemies in the game can drop them as well, just at an incredibly low rate.

So my question is in 3 parts:

- Which NPC's drop Awestones?
- At what rate do other enemies drop Awestones?
- Can I increase my chances of finding them, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get awestones is by defeating invading red phantoms, which will drop one each time.

The farming strategy that I know involves simply farming them off of the scripted NPC invader Rhoy the Explorer in the Grave of Saints.

In that area Rhoy the Explorer will spawn 15 times and drop an awestone each time before having to use a bonfire ascetic.